# O-minimal spectrum is a spectral space

Tags: model-theory

I'm trying to understand a proof on "Sheaves of Continuous Definable Functions" (Pillay, Anand. "Sheaves of continuous definable functions." The Journal of symbolic logic 53.04 (1988): 1165-1169.)

Let $\mathcal{N} = (N,<,\ldots)$ be an o-minimal structure and let $X \subset N^m$ be a definable set, the o-minimal spectrum $X^\sim$ of $X$ is the set of complete m-types $S_m(N)$ of the first-order theory $Th_N (\mathcal{N})$
which imply a formula defining X equipped with the topology generated by
the basic open sets of the form
$$U^\sim = \{p \in X^\sim : U ∈ p\}$$
where U is a definable, relatively open subset of X. We call this topology on $X^\sim$ the spectral topology.

My goal is to understand why is $X^\sim$ a spectral space. Let $F \subset X^\sim$ be a closed, irreducible space. 
The proof goes along the lines: Let $\Phi = \{B \subset X : B $ is closed, definable and $B \in p$ for every $p \in F\}$ and then $\Phi'= \{ X \setminus C: C$ closed, definable and $C \notin \Phi\}$, and $\Phi_1 = \Phi \cup \Phi'$ and argues that, since $F$ is irreducible, $\Phi_1$ is consistent.

I already know that $\Phi$ is consistent (since $\Phi \subset p$ for every $p \in F$) and that for every $\varphi \in \Phi'$ either $\Phi \cup \varphi$ or $\Phi \cup \lnot \varphi$ is consistent. But I can't relate that to $F$ irreducibleness.

Comment: Crossposted at mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/242570/o-minimal-spectrum-is-a-spectral-space.

Comment: Jonas: A convention here (and at Math Overflow) is that one should not post the same question to both sites. An exception is that if a question is posted here and does not receive an adequate answer after some reasonable amount of time, it may be cross posted there. I've provided an answer to your question over on MO.

Comment: @AlexKruckman thank you for your answer on MO and your comment here. Soon after I posted the question here I realized that I should have posted on MO instead, because the question qualifies (I believe) as a research-level question. By the way, I'm carefully reading your answer and it's already helping a lot.